# Auto Authenticating with Microsoft Office.js Add-ins

Tags: javascript, azure, office365, adal.js

**Backgroud**

I am currently working on Microsoft Office add-in, using Office Js.  The add in is a simple UI that will make a call to a web api which will run a service for the intended user.  I currently have that web api protected by Azure Ad.  This prompts the user to sign in on their firm issued pc and insert their credentials.  I am looking towards the future here when I say I will get kick back by users asking why must they sign in again, when they are already signing into firm issued pc's using the same credential.

**Question**

Is there a way that I can aquire an auto sign in flow using credentials which were already used in order to sign in to the pc? I understand this may be a security issue because of javascript.  But is there an alternative which can provide the user with an auto sign in flow?

**Misc. Info**

I have seen that when ever I open a MS suite app, it shows my name automatically on the top right.  This tells me that the office app is aquire my credential already.  So I am hoping I can some how tap into that or mimic it in a way using office.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can configure Internet Explorer for Automatic Logon.

*For this type of authentication to take place, the following two things must be true: the user must be running a browser that supports Kerberos and/or NTLM authentication; and, that browser must be configured to allow for automatic logon to a Communicator Web Access site. You can configure Internet Explorer for automatic logon by completing the following procedure on each client computer.*

*You can configure these settings by using Group Policy too. By using Group Policy, you can configure client computers without having to log on to each computer.*

*To configure Internet Explorer for automatic logon:*

1. Open the Internet Options dialog box by choosing Internet Options either from Control Panel or from the Tools menu in Internet Explorer.
2. In the Internet Options dialog box, on the Security tab, select Local intranet, and then click Custom Level.
3. In the Security Settings dialog box, under Logon, select Automatic logon only in Intranet zone, and then click OK.
4. In the Internet Options dialog box on the Security Settings tab with Local intranet still selected, click Sites.
5. In the Local intranet dialog box, click Advanced.
6. In the next dialog box (also titled Local intranet), type the URL of your Communicator Web Access site (for example, https://cwaserver.contoso.com) in the Add this Web site to the zone box, and then click Add.
7. In the Local intranet dialog, box click OK.
8. In the original Local intranet dialog box, click OK.
9. In the Internet Options dialog box, click OK.

*To configure Internet Explorer for automatic logon by using Group Policy*

1. Open the Group Policy Management Console, and then either create a new Group Policy Object (GPO) or edit an existing GPO.
2. Expand Computer Configuration, expand Policies, expand Administrative Templates, expand Windows Components, expand Internet Explorer, expand Internet Control Panel, and then click Security Page.
3. In the details pane, double-click Site to Zone Assignment List.
4. In the Site to Zone Assignment List Properties dialog box, click Enabled.
5. In the Site to Zone Assignment List Properties dialog box, click Show.
6. In the Show Contents dialog box, click Add.
7. In the Add Item dialog box, type the URL of your Communicator Web Access site (for example, https://cwaserver.contoso.com) in the Enter the name of the item to be added box.
8. Type 1 (indicating the local intranet zone) in the Enter the value of the item to be added box, and then click OK.
9. In the Show Contents dialog box, click OK.
10. In the Site to Zone Assignment List dialog box, click OK.
11. In the Group Policy Management Editor, click Intranet Zone.
12. In the details pane, double-click Logon options.
13. In the Logon options Properties dialog box, click Enabled.
14. In the Logon options list, click Automatic logon only in Intranet zone, and then click OK.
15. Close the Group Policy Management Editor.

More detail please refer to [Configuring Internet Explorer for Automatic Logon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572939%28v=office.13%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).